# How do I add an image value to h:commandlink?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Can someone please tell me how I would add an image value to this code instead of a text value?

```xml
<h:commandLink 
    action="#{gridHandlerXml.removeLinesFromGroups}"
    render="quote-table, totalPanel, revisionTabs" execute="@this"
    disabled="#{currentQuote.convertInProgress}" 
    onclick="#{rich:component('fcprocessing:processingpopup')}.show()" 
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('fcprocessing:processingpopup')}.hide()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite straightforward: Just embed an an `h:graphicImage` in the command link:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{gridHandlerXml.removeLinesFromGroups}">
    <h:graphicImage url="resources/path/to/your/image"/>
</h:commandLink>
```